# How to write a shell script to find perfect number from 1 to 100

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

Problem image

[image]

below code is running in an infinite loop and not giving any output.
So I'm unable to understand what is the problem with the code.

I'm a beginner in shell scripting.

current code

```
#!/bin/sh

sum=0
i=1
p=1

echo "Perfect numbers from 1 and 100 are" 

while [ $i -le 100 ]
    p=1
do
    while [ $p -le  $((i / 2)) ]
    do
        if [ $((i % p)) -eq 0 ]
        then 
            sum=$($sum + $p)
        fi
        p=$($p + 1)
    done
    if [ "$sum" -eq $i ]
    then 
    echo $i
    sum=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: Start by reading the bash manual to find the proper syntax for `while` and running your script through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Hi I was trying to run it on one online compiler. I have attached the screenshot

Comment: I have updated changes done on shellcheck still its not giving any error but also not getting any output

Comment: Now you have 2 different codes in your question and no explanation of what they are, except that the other one is "current"

Comment: I have rewritten the whole code. I have tried to put the logic for finding perfect numbers from 1 to 100 in shell script. with the help of shellcheck.net but in output nothing is happening. Let me delete the first one and please tell me what am doing wrong in secod code

Comment: @lieven `-le` is perfectly good shell script; it's what `test` (aka `[`) uses for numeric comparisons, mainly because `<` is already reserved for redirection (which is no doubt why Powesrshell copied this syntax).

Comment: You are using `$(...)` instead of `$((...))` in a couple of places; this will try to run `...` as a command and return its output, which of course fails spectacularly if what you have there is not a valid command.

Comment: For debugging, try running your script with `sh -vx`, probably outside of any fancy IDE. You'll need to look up what these options do and spend a few minutes figuring out what the output means.

Comment: `while [ $i -le 100 ]; p=1; do` is an infinite loop.  You probably meant `while [ "$i" -le 100 ]; do p=1; ...`

Answer (score 2):

The infinite loops is coming from the construct:

```
while [ $i -le 100 ]
    p=1
do
```

you almost certainly meant to write:

```
while [ "$i" -le 100 ]
do
    p=1
```

The syntax for `while` is: `while cmd; cmd; cmd; ....; do`
and the loop body is entered if the final command succeeds.  `p=1` will always succeed, so you have an infinite loop.

Comment: I did the change. Now M getting error as :                                                       
{main.bash: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `done'        
main.bash: line 22: `done'}